# JMeter - Access JSR223 variable in HTTP sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a variable in JSR223 and I need to call that variable in HTTP sampler.
For example, I have a variable as mentioned below.

```
Jsondata = ''' {
    "name": "Foo Bar",
    "year": "2018",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-08T00:00:00",
    "tags": [
        "person",
        "employee"
    ],
    "grade": 3.14
}
'''
```

I'm calling the variable in body data of HTTP request sampler like below, but it's printing itself and not converting to actual value.

```
${Jsondata}
```

The output which i am getting in result tree is 
`${Jsondata}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSR223 script put groovy variable value into JMeter variable using `vars`

```
vars.put("Jsondata", Jsondata);
```

Comment: @RafiqShaikh you can accept and upvote if it helped